# How can I specify the direction of motion in the colvars file?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, namd, enhanced-sampling

I am doing umbrella sampling in NAMD and I want to control the distance in the colvars to be in one direction. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the collars module to achieve the same. Your colvars file would look something like this

```
distanceZ {
       
      main {
            atom numbers of the group that you want to move
      }
      ref {
            atom numbers of the group that you are keeping constant
      }
      axis (0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
}
```

Comment: I already tried before, but I tried again and I didnt see my LIG move toward the center of lipid and the LIG move in a certain region without decreasing the distance between the LIG and the ref. When I use distance option, I can move the LIG toward the center of the lipid, but I can't specify the direction motion.

Comment: I have done this during my PhD (you can refer my [papers](https://doi.org/10.1039/D0NR08796C)), but without seeing your original files, I cannot troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Maybe in your case, you want the movement of the nucleobases over the graphene(I just got the idea from TOC). But in my case I want to move the LIG toward the center of the bilayer lipid exactly, therefore it will pass through the lipids to reach the center. In my case, it seems to be y direction because my bilayer lipid size is (70,170,70).

Comment: This would be my last comment here (because the comment chain is getting longer) if you see Figure S7 in the SI, you will see that I have computed the interaction energy between two nucleobases, and used the z-projected distance between the nucleases as the CV. **This** is why I mentioned that the same method might work for you, but each for ourselves I guess.